# My name contains a special (non-ASCII) character (e.g. é, ø, â, Ö) and I can't create a wallet with the GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Basically title. The GUI doesn't let me create a wallet even if I specify a different wallet directory. Is there any workaround so I can use the GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with explaining in detail why this happens. This issue is basically the result of two bugs and is *Windows* specific. First, upon creating a new wallet, the GUI creates a temporary wallet file in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\`. It'll use this temporary directory regardless of the directory specified for the wallet. Therefore, even if you specified a different directory, the GUI will be unable to create a wallet because it can't store the temporary file. Second, the GUI only supports UTF-8 input strings for the wallet path and therefore is unable to create a wallet file that contains special characters. Likewise, it'll be unable to load a wallet file that is stored in a directory whose path contains a special character.

Fortunately, however, there is a quick workaround that allows you to create a wallet and use the GUI. Perform the following steps:

1. Browse to the directory `monero-wallet-gui.exe` is located.
2. Open `monero-wallet-cli.exe` by double clicking on it.
3. Enter a new wallet name + password. It'll also give you the 25 word mnemonic seed, make sure to note it down, i.e., make a back up of it.
4. After creating the wallet, exit `monero-wallet-cli` by typing `exit`
5. Open `monero-wallet-gui.exe`
6. On the second page of the wizard (first page is the language selection), choose `Open a wallet from file`
7. Now browse to the same directory as `monero-wallet-gui` / `monero-wallet-cli`. There should be a `<wallet-name>.keys` file (this is the wallet you just created with `monero-wallet-cli`). Select it.

You should now be able to use the GUI :)